Should we accept questions on all construction toys, or just LEGO compatible systems?
I guess we need to bottom this out once and for all - during the commitment phase a discussion was started, but didn't really resolve:
Is this site only about LEGO products and other brick based toys, or is it open to all construction toys including K-Nex and Meccano (for example)?

in my oppinion, this site should cover model construction toys in general, wich means:

LEGO and all of it's subsets (DUPLO, Technik, Mindstorms, ZNAP, ...)
other brick-based toys (similar to DUPLO, Minifigures, LEGO-System) (KRE-O, Nanoblocks, ...)
other beam/bar-based toys (similar to ZNAP, LEGO-Technik) (K'Nex, Meccano, fischertechnik)


I'm more inclined to allow K'Nex than Meccano that's for sure. However I wouldn't see why general wood working would have to be included - If we did allow Meccano we would have a hard time excluding sets like "Wood WorX" which come with pre-cut wooden shapes and instructions on how to build a fire engine or similar (although they do use glue, so could be excluded on that basis)

I feel like that its best that this remain only LEGO considering the size of the LEGO community and the diversity of their products. There are also no "modern" LEGO community websites, that I have found, and I can see this SE becoming a canoical LEGO site.
